# multer upload file with body and validation and save file name to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

My code looks like this:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req: Request, file: any, cb: any) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename(req: Request, file: any, cb: any) {
    cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage, limits: { fieldSize: `${UPLOAD_LIMIT}MB` } });

router.route('/post').post(upload.single('file'), validate(createPost), controller.createPost);
```

createPost validation looks like this:

```
  createPost: {
    body: Joi.object({
      email: Joi.string().email(),
      title: Joi.string().min(1).max(128),
      message: Joi.string().min(2).max(5000).required(),
      hidden: Joi.boolean().required(),
      embed: Joi.string().min(6).max(128),
      password: Joi.string().min(6).max(128)
    })
  },
```

createPost controller looks like this:

```
exports.createPost = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const { threadId } = req.params;
  try {
    const newPost = new Post(req.body);
    const data = await newPost.save();
    apiJson({ req, res, data, model: newPost });
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
};
```

And my questions are:

1. How to pass newly generated filename of saved file to my createPost controller?
2. Will my validation work correctly? Validating body and file in different places?

Comment: 1) you can get saved filrname and other details of file in  `controller.createPost` using `req.file` 2) for validation you need to call middleware function, you can check validation using `Joi.validate(req.body, createPost)`

Comment: @turivishal but how to validate both file and body with middleware function?

Comment: I am not sure joi will do that, but you can not validate both together, first it will upload file and than validate body params, this is unfortunate problem. i am suggesting you to do both in different request, file upload in different request api and form submit in different request api.